# CSS library (ex:Bootstrap) that supports IE6?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-6, cascade-framework

I was a happy user of [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

But most of our users are now from [China, where IE6 is at 37%](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-CN-monthly-201010-201110).
So we must abandon Bootstrap, which [does not support IE6](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/76).

Any library similar to Bootstrap (simplify HTML/CSS layout) that supports IE6 too?

Comment: are people in china not allowed to upgrade their IE?

Comment: also, i'm not entirely sure what bootstrap is, but looking at the front page, it looks similar to grid 960. does that not meet your needs? http://960.gs/

Comment: @Mark: In short: software piracy (see http://bradweikel.com/software-piracy-china-why-ie6-will-not-die-2010)

Comment: @Mark: looks great and seems to work on IE6, feel free to propose it as an answer.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Done =) Interesting article! Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Grid 960](http://960.gs/)?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), a rock-solid default for building sites using HTML + CSS + JS.

Comment: Are you sure it still supports IE6?

Answer (score 4):

I had a small degrade on a site we have that uses bootstrap on IE 7 and 8, but IE 6 was just awful. I applied the CSS on the [Bootstrap-IE6](https://github.com/guoguo/Bootstrap-IE6) project and it looks pretty like IE 7 now. It's not perfect but a massive improvement on what I had.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Cascade Framework](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/). It's a CSS framework I released earlier this year that's almost as fully featured as Bootstrap and offers full support for IE6.